# 10 most recent rows from mySQL by time and define variables

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get the 10 most recent rows from a mysql database.

How can I do that?

```
+----+-------+----+-----------+
| id | value | ap | timestamp |
+----+-------+----+-----------+
```

And define variables for value, ap, and timestamp... **for each row!**

like:

```
    $value1 = ?;
    $ap1 = ?;
    $timestamp1 = ?;

    $value2 = ?;
    $ap2 = ?;
    $timestamp2 = ?;
etc....
```

Comment: I don't understand the second part of your question. Can you clarify?

Comment: The mysql_fetch returns an array -- no need for separate variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is probably something like this:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=<hostname>;port=<port>;dbname=<database name>', '<username>', '<password>');

$query = 'SELECT id, value, ap, `timestamp` '.
            'FROM <table> '.
            'ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC '.
            'LIMIT 10';

$resultset = $db->query($query);

$results = $resultset->fetchAll();
```

Then you will have a two-dimensional array with 10 sets of the values you want. `$results[0]['id']`, `$results[0]['value']`, `$results[0]['ap']`, and `$results[0]['timestamp']`, up through `$results[9]['id']`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the data like so..

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `my_table` ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC LIMIT 10");
```

and you can use the results like so..

```
while($results = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
    echo $results->value; 
    echo $results->ap;
    echo $results->timestamp; 
}
```